# supportFragmentManager.commit in kotlin is not working

Tags: java, android, kotlin, fragment

Can anyone help me with this please? Inside my fragment supportFragmentManager.commit{} is not working. Android Studio is not recognizing this I don't know what to do. I am working in kotlin project

[image]

Comment: try **`.beginTransaction().commit()`**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That `commit {}` method (with the transaction in a lambda) is an extension function provided by the [Fragment KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#fragment) library. If you haven't already, you need to add this dependency in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
}
```

and then Android Studio should automatically offer to fix the `commit` call by importing it. If it doesn't (it can be awkward sometimes), add this to your imports:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.commit
```

and maybe these too, I don't know if they'll be necessary

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
```

you might need to remove some other matching imports so you're just using the `androidx` versions